# Xubuntu blank screen after wakeup

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, xfce, bug-reporting

Xubuntu 14.04. After wake up from sleep, it asks to enter password. I entered the passw. and screen goes black. On Ubuntu 14.04 waking up was just ok. Lenovo E330 laptop with intel HD graphics.
add: If lid was closed, not clicked sleep

Comment: Perhaps this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1303736 ?

Comment: I just uninstalled lightlocker and installed xcreensaver.

Answer (score 3):

This is all great and fine. But for a noob or anyone who is not accustomed to CLI it doesn't make the problem any less bothersome. Here is the solution that worked for me.

- Completely remove Light Locker using Synaptic Package Manager
- Install Gnome Screensaver from the Ubuntu Software Center
- Restart the computer

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, one day when I fresh installed Xubuntu, that problem stopped. Still, if this happen, try using the following tip:

1. Get into the command line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Put your credentials user/password.
3. Write the following:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```

So it will take you back to the login screen.

Hope that helps! (It's not a fix for this problem, though. I had to get used to click the Suspend button instead of closing the lid.)

Comment: Doesn't Xubuntu use `xdm` as its default display manager instead of `lightdm`?

Comment: I can't give a full certain answer about it, but as a solution for that problem, it worked that way. I made that supposition because of how my given solution has worked for me, but I will edit it.

Comment: Problem with this, you need root access. I have to bug my boss to run this. All the same, good answer, should be the accepted answer. Note that on different models (hardware related? not sure) there is a range of Ctrl-Alt-FKeys that will open a text-based login, some I have seen, this only works on F4-F7. Off the top of my head (booted into Windows now, heresy, I know) I think it's Ctrl-Alt-F3 that gets you back to the graphical login?

Comment: @JimLohse In Xubuntu, it is Ctrl+Alt+F7, if I'm not wrong. Now I'm Fedora, which is a different command, as you said

Comment: This worked for me but it restarted the session except for few windows. Is that expected?

Answer (score 2):

Easier way:
Switch to different session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>)
and then back to your session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: This did not work for me. On a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around the problem by going into settings, opening "Light Locker Settings" and setting "Enable light-locker" to off.

Learn more about light locker at http://xubuntu.org/news/screen-locking-in-xubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Click on Light Locker Setting does not work for me. No action after click. No program appears. I see dim light on wake-up and there Xubuntu stops.

Answer (score 0):

My Lenovo E531 does the same. I insert the password and the screen goes black. Then I press the power button, I enter the password (again!) and everything it's fine. I know it's not the answer you needed, it's just a workaround than works for me. I hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem too. My solution was on Light Locker Settings too but I didn't disable light locker. I just enabled "Lock on suspend" and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from WolfangAukang helped me. But in my case, it was sddm which had to be restarted.

Get into the command line using Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Put your credentials user/password.

Write the following:

```
sudo service sddm restart
```

So it will take you back to the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in light-locker on most laptops. A workaround is, using suspend instead of xflock4. This can be achieved changing the next three options in XFCE4:

- Whiskers menu > right click > settings > commands > lock screen -> and write 'systemctl suspend' instead of 'xflock4'
- Settings panel > power manager > security > lock session automatically > never
- Settings panel > session and start > advanced > lock screen before suspend > unchecked

An easier workaround is just installing xscreensaver. It's ugly, but it works.