# How to prevent Xubuntu from suspend?

Tags: 16.04, power-management, hibernate, lock-screen

Apparently, Xubuntu is totally unable to wake up. So when it goes to sleep, for whatever reason, **you lose all usaved work**. No <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, nothing. It is there, the machine is on, but the only thing you can do is a *hard* shut down.

After [various](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462361/xubuntu-blank-screen-after-wakeup) [unsuccessful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450387/screen-switches-off-after-waking-up-from-suspend) [attempts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517067/how-to-wake-xubuntu-desktop-from-sleep) at correcting the problem, I just turned off all power management options.

[image: tab1] [image: tab2] [image: tab3]

But **it still goes to sleep/death** after 45 minutes, the default setting.

What can I do to just turn off all sleep functions?

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 on a Intel NUC. Before that I was using plain Ubuntu on this same machine (but it took too much RAM) and it could wake up without any problem.

Comment: Did you make bug reports about the issues?

Comment: @Jarno The problem has already been reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1581249

Answer (score 2):

### Caffeine

You could give caffeine a try - quoting the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/caffeine):

> A status bar application able to temporarily prevent the activation of
>   both the screensaver and the "sleep" powersaving mode.

Comment: I'd rather uninstall something :) BTW I removed "light locker" but no luck. Anybody here knows what process is actually handling the suspend?

Comment: This isn't helpful if your XUbuntu is a headless node.